# I don't see ability to delete old version from Flurry

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

How to delete unused versions from Flurry? 
Seems like i have more than 1000 versions for my app and therefore i don't see new versions.

In old versions of the design it was possible to delete old versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete versions on the Admin > Versions dashboard.

1. Click the Admin tab(The icon that looks like a wrench)
2. Click "Versions" on the left nav bar
3. Select the app at the top
4. Use the checkboxes to choose which versions to delete
5. Use the "Action" Menu at the top to choose to delete